# Like Box "see more" does not work

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have put a Like Box on our website and works fine with one exception... in longer posts it gives you a clickable "see more" option to expand the post within the box.  When I click "see more" nothing happens.

I've moved everything to a test page at www.cucharavillage.com/test.html just so I could play with different code options and try to figure it out.

It does not work in Firefox or IE.  Any suggestions?